# ODE change of variables with matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Given a 1D ODE as $\dot{x}=A x + B x(1-x) $,

we can do a change of variable to $y=\ln{[\frac{x}{1-x}]}$ such that now we have

$\dot{y}= A (1+e^y)+B$

While this system might or not be more difficult to solve, it is a valid change of variables.

Now, given a set of $NxN$ matrices, that fulfill this same matrix ODE

$\dot{\textbf{x}}=\textbf{A} \textbf{x} + \textbf{B} \textbf{x}(1-\textbf{x})$,

where $\textbf{x}$ is a matrix. Specifically, with $Tr[\textbf{x}]=1$ and positive semidefinite. About the interpretation of $\textbf{x}(1-\textbf{x})$, it would just be the matrix product of $\textbf{x}$ and $\mathcal{I}-\textbf{x}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ woud be the identity.

Is it valid to perform the same change of variables?

Comment: $\textbf{X}$ is a matrix. Specifically, with $Tr[\textbf{X}]=1$ and positive semidefinite. About the interpretation of $\textbf{x}(1-\textbf{x})$, it would just be the matrix product of $\textbf{X}$ and $\mathcal{I}-\textbf{X}$, where $\mathcal{I}$ woud be the identity. However, this is just a toy example to illustrate the generalization of the 1D case.

Comment: Awesome, Please update the question with that info as it is sure to help answerers

Comment: To be clear, the matrix transform you are talking about is $\mathbf{y} = \log (\mathbf{x}(I-\mathbf{x})^{-1})$, correct?

Comment: For this specific case, this would be the transformation. Still, I would like to point out that I like to understand it generically, under what circumstances we make this change of variables. My guess would be that as long as the inverse exists, i.e. the matrix is not singular, there would be no problem.

Comment: You need the inverse to exist and for $\|\mathbf{x}(I-\mathbf{x})^{-1}\| <1$ so that the matrix logarithm is well-defined. I would also very carefully check that the change of variables actually does what you want, because the derivatives will become a lot more complicated in the matrix case due to the lack of commutativity.